# Jquery price increase by slab

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on some project and I'm facing some issue
actually i want price increase by slap like i am allowing customer to select guest for booking for e.g the main price of product is 100 and additional price of guest is 50 and limit of guest is 4 when customer select 5 guest then the main price should be add in total price after when customer select 6 guest then only add 50 price i am sharing some code but its not working properly.

main price = 100
addintion price = 50

| Guest | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 250 |
| 5 | 350 add main price again (100) |
| 6 | 400 |
| 7 | 450 |
| 8 | 500 |
| 9 | 600 add main price again (100) |
| 10 | 650 |

```
group_size = 4;
increased_group_size = 4;
total_guests = me.guests;
if(total_guests<=group_size){
    increased_group_size -= group_size;
    if(increased_group_size==0){
        increased_group_size += group_size;
    }
}

if(total_guests>increased_group_size){
    main_price = main_price;
    increased_group_size += group_size;
    final_price += main_price;
}
else{
    
    final_price1 = total_guests * me.addtional_price;
}
total += final_price1 + final_price + me.price;
```

I tried the above code but not working properly.

Comment: You don't have default values for `final_price` and `final_price1`, and you only assign one or the other.

Comment: Why isn't the `final_price1` assignment in the `if`? The `else` block is the same condition.

Comment: Where are 100 and 50 in the code?

Comment: the default value is define and its 0

Comment: me.price is 100 and me.addtional_price is 50

Comment: What's the point of `main_price = main_price;`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your description of the pricing. Can you add some sample desired results?

Comment: its mistake before i use like this main_price += main_price

Comment: https://www.raynatours.com/city-tour/tour-details/Private-Desert-Safari-Dubai-5134.aspx
open this website page and you see there is option to select adult option try to increase the price when you select 4 the price will same but when you select 5 then its increase the price

Comment: Everything relevant should be in the question, not at some link that might change in the future.

Comment: can you help me out how i can do like this

Comment: I can't help you until you explain it so I can understand.

Comment: did you see this link https://www.raynatours.com/city-tour/tour-details/Private-Desert-Safari-Dubai-5134.aspx

Comment: 1 adult = 367.60, 2 adults = 398.23, 3 adults = 428.86, 4 adults = 459.50, 5 adults = 490.13, 6 adults = 520.76. So it's 30.63 for adult 2 and 3, 30.64 for adult 4, 30.63 for adults 5 and 6.

Comment: They're all the same price, except for 1 extra cent for adult 4, that's probably because you're using fractions and it's rounding differently.

Comment: yes and when you add adult 7 the main price 367 added again in total

Comment: try to add adult 7

Comment: Why should everyone reading this question have to play with the web site? Just put the information in the question to make it easier on us. Who knows if that site will still be there in 5 years?

Comment: i am really sorry for this but i am confused how i describe in detail. again really sorry.

Comment: Just write a table showing the prices for 1 through 10 guests, using your example prices of 50 and 100.

Comment: please check i create a table for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the number of additional guests by the group size. For each group, add the difference between the main price and additional price.

```js
function calculate_price(total_guests) {
  let additional_guests = total_guests - 1;
  let group_size = 4;
  let additional_groups = Math.floor(additional_guests / group_size);
  let main_price = 100;
  let additional_price = 50;

  let total_price = main_price + additional_guests * additional_price + additional_groups * (main_price - additional_price);
  return total_price;
}

for (let guests = 1; guests <= 10; guests++) {
  console.log(`Guests = ${guests} Price = ${calculate_price(guests)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you need to do is check whether the current number is divisible by your max number. Then add one number if it is, and another number if it isn't.

Here's a working example.

```js
const guestNum = $(".guests-total");
const total = $(".total");

$(".button").on("click", (e) => {
  let numMult = 1;
  const num = parseInt(guestNum.text());
  let curTotal = parseInt(total.text());
  let testNum = num + 1;

  if (e.target.classList[1] === "min") {
    numMult = -1;
    testNum = num;
    if (num === 0) {
      return;
    }
  }

  while (testNum > 0) {
    testNum = testNum - 5;
  }

  if (testNum !== 0) {
    curTotal += numMult * 50;
    guestNum.text(num + numMult * 1);
    total.text(curTotal);
    return;
  }

  curTotal += numMult * 100;
  guestNum.text(num + numMult * 1);
  total.text(curTotal);
  return;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  gap: 2vw;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3vw;
}

.icon-test {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row-one">
      <div class="button min">-</div>
      <div class="guests-total">0</div>
      <div class="button add">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-two">
      <div class="money-total">Total: $<span class="total">0</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Let's break this down.

Here we get the DOM elements for the number of guests and the sub-total of money.

```
const guestNum = $(".guests-total");
const total = $(".total");
```

Then we register an event listener for a click on the button to either add or subtract a guest.

```
$(".button").on("click", (e) => {
```

I set a variable called *numMult* that I will multiply all my sub-total numbers by to either subtract or add money (I'll explain that more later).

```
let numMult = 1;
```

Then I get the actual text contained in the DOM elements and convert those to integers so we can add or subtract from them.

```
const num = parseInt(guestNum.text());
let curTotal = parseInt(total.text());
```

Finally I make a new variable that will be used to test if the current number is a multiple of 5 or not.

```
let testNum = num + 1;
```

Here we check if the button that was clicked is the *subtract* button or the *add* button, if it's the subtract button then we will be multiplying all our numbers by -1 so that it subtracts from the subtotal instead of adds to it.

If the current number is 0 we return because there obviously can't be *negative* guests.

```
if (e.target.classList[1] === "min") {
  numMult = -1;
  testNum = num;
  if (num === 0) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Here we subtract from the total number of guests until *num* is less than or equal to zero.

```
while (testNum > 0) {
  testNum = testNum - 5;
}
```

If our test number doesn't come out as zero, we know that the number isn't 5 or divisible by 5, so we add or subtract 50.

```
if (testNum !== 0) {
  curTotal += numMult * 50;
  guestNum.text(num + numMult * 1);
  total.text(curTotal);
  return;
}
```

Otherwise, if our test number *is* 0, we know that the number of guests is either 5 or a multiple of 5, so we add 100.

```
curTotal += numMult * 100;
guestNum.text(num + numMult * 1);
total.text(curTotal);
return;
```

I hope this helps out.